# My datetime-local input field is showing in 24hr time when viewed on Chromebook, how do I get back to 12hr time?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="partyDate" id="partyDate" >
```

The input field shows as dd/mm/yyyy, -:-- on my new Chromebook

My other computers also using Chrome browser see it in 12hr time, so it is something in the Chromebook settings. 
The input field shows as dd-----yyyy --:-- --  (local OS (winxp) date settings set to dd/MMM/yyyy and 12 hour time)

Time settings in the Chromebook is not set to 24hr time.

I am not sure where else to look as I am new to Chrome OS.

I would prefer to fix this without having to replace the datetime-local input field.

Thanks

EDIT - by changing the Chrome language from English UK to English US I got back the 12hr time, which technically answers the question, but an extension question: is there a setting I can change to have it display 29-May-2015 rather than 05-29-2015 like good ol Microsoft lets me?

Comment: Can you post your HTML or any other relevant code?

Comment: A search for "[chromebook settings date time](https://www.google.com/search?q=chromebook+settings+date+time)" gives [this](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/177871) as the first result.

Comment: Thanks Mogsdad, but its the date and time format that is displayed in browser that I am wanting to change, not the OS time display format

Answer (score 0):

Seems the default language of the Chromebook is English-UK which defines how dates are displayed. By changing the language to English-US, dates in the browser are now showing in 12hr format